# Netbeans not keeping added server after restart

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

When I add a new server (glassfish) or another, it works just fine. I can startup the server and deploy apps on it.

But, every time I restart netbeans the added servers are not there. It means I must add servers every time I open netbeans.

I'm using netbeans7.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are on windows, you have probably run into a variant of http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=197950. We plan on including a fix for this in NB 7.0.1

Comment: I'm having issue still... (and open same question. ouch) but this hasn't been answered.. its been six month plus and not been addressed..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is not happening any more on netbeans 7.2. If it was a bug, it has been fixed.