# Do I have to add Glassfish3.1 server with Netbean 7.0.1 every time?

Tags: glassfish-3, netbeans-7

Environment
Windows 7, Netbean 7.0.1

I downloaded `Netbean 7.0.1` bundle with `Glassfish 3.1`.
But I removed `Glassfish 3.1` from Netbean IDE and then I choose to "Add server" from service tab in Netbean IDE because I have `Glassfish 3.1 Multilingual version` in my C drive.

Right after I added the Glassfish server, I can start it by right click on my project and run the server.

**However when I close the Netbean IDE and restart the IDE and try to run the server by right click on my project, execute the project, the log says server is starting but it hangs there and the server won't start.**

I made sure the port is not occupied too. (if occupied it should say so in the log but log does not throw any errors)

So my question is do I have to remove the server, add server every time I start Netbean when I don't use bundled Glassfish? (most likely not though..)

repro step:
1. install Netbean 7.0.1
2. from IDE service tab, right click on Glassfish3.1 and remove it.
3. at service tab, right click and choose add server
4. choose Glassfish 3.1 server that is separately downloaded (i.e. not bundled)
5. go back to project tab, choose to run the project
6. verify that project successfully deployed, Glassfish 3.1 is started, browser popup up.
7. close Netbean 7.0 
8. start Netbean 7.0 
9. at the project tab, choose to run the project

result:
The glassfish 3.1 won't start.

I found out the db log is showing port 1527 is in use (could figure out at first because Netbean Japanese version has encoding issue?)

```
2011-12-12 04:21:38.040 GMT : セキュリティーマネージャーが Basic サーバーセキュリティーポリシーを使用してインストールされました。
2011-12-12 04:21:38.263 GMT : Apache Derby Network Server - 10.5.3.0 - (802917) ????μ∑?????????????????? 1527 ???????∂?????????????????∫??????????‰∫?????????????
```

Searched around, some say end process of java.exe fixes the problem which did not help.

I also tried netstat -aon after Netbean restart, but I do not see 1527 port in use...

Update:

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic42385.html

I figured that I have exactly same problem described in the link above. Still searching for solution to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269461/netbeans-not-keeping-added-server-after-restart I've checked this same question and it should be addressed in Netbean 7.0.1... weird..

Comment: i'm downloading Netbean 7.1 RC2 and see if same thing happens...(i'm so wondering not able to find information on this issue cuz at least some ppl should be facing this problem)

Answer (score 0):

Adding server to your project:

Select your project, right click on it. Select properties. then Select Run categories, In Server field you can choose which server you want from the dropdown box, then select Ok button.